# Javascript how to output from option selection without reloading output in a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

Readjusting wording of problem.
I have the below code. I have an HTML file and JS file separately. I have set my css file with all margins, etc  and outputs some text ... so css margins and colours work. When pressing on the drop down and the function displayArray() is called all my css adjustments dissapear and the ouput is like screenshot I will be inputing. I think the error is in the document.write

I'm sry I am bad at explaining and if someone understood me do you have any idea what line of code is needed. Thank you

```js
function menu() {
  var input = document.getElementById("opt").value;
  switch (input) {
    case "1":
      Numbers(1, 1000);
      BS();
      displayArray();
      break;
  }
}


function displayArray(){  
  //Display Array 
  for (var i= 0 ; i <length; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i]);
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select id="opt" onChange="menu()">
    <option value="0" selected>Sorting</option>
    <option value="1">bubble sort</option>
    <option value="2">selection sort</option>
    <option value="3">quick sort</option>
    <option value="4">insertion sort</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script>
  function option() {
    menu();
  }
</script>
```

[image: How it looks]
[image: output when pressing selection. I want output to be displayed under the from down not in a blank page]

Comment: Is there an ajax call that happens in `BS()` or `displayArray()` ? If so, have you tried to `return false` at the end of that ajax call?

Comment: I don't really understand the term ajax. But BS is a bubble sort which is a loop to sort random numbers and display array outputs the array in a for loop and doesn't stop until it displays all sorted numbers. I hope it helps let me know if adding more code would be more helpful

Comment: About AJAX: https://code-boxx.com/submit-form-without-refreshing-page

Comment: thanks i am looking at it

Comment: `window.confirm("Bubble Sort");` makes no sense since you do nothing with the return value of confirm.

Comment: In that code there is nothing that will make the page reload. So you need to show more code.

Comment: yeah thanks I have just adjusted it to document.writeln to output it as a sentence and outputs results of sorted array under it

Comment: You should never use document.write.... That is why your page is "reloading" since you are replacing it.

Comment: ah ok! sorry if this question is being stupid but i'm still new to js, html, css so excuse me for being not as much informed of these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I substituted the missing functions to show you a working example.

```js
function menu() {
  var input = document.getElementById("opt").value;
  switch (input) {
    case "1":
      //window.confirm("Bubble Sort"); Don't need this
      var numberstoSort = Numbers(1, 1000);
      var sortedNumbers = BubbleSort();
      displayArray(sortedNumbers);
      break;
  }
}

function Numbers(min, max) {
  // Use your min/max to get the numbers in random order
  // example list below of 10 numbers
  return "878, 436, 196, 669, 49, 900, 215, 106, 747, 529";
}

function BubbleSort(numberstoSort) {
  // Perform your sort
  return "49, 106, 196, 215, 436, 529, 669, 747, 878, 900";
}

function displayArray(sortedNumbers) {
  // Standard Javascript
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Your sorted numbers are: " + sortedNumbers;

  // JQuery answer below
  //$("div.results").text("Your sorted numbers are: " + sortedNumbers);
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select id="opt" onChange="menu()">
    <option value="0" selected>Sorting</option>
    <option value="1">bubble sort</option>
    <option value="2">selection sort</option>
    <option value="3">quick sort</option>
    <option value="4">insertion sort</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: i am still adjusting the code so far im at same problem im going to edit my code above and show my displayArray cos I think that's the main issue of the problem. altough your code did help me understand some things more

Comment: The problem is docuent.write(). That overwrites your whole document. You need a container to put your results in. Notice in `displayArray()` I set the `innerHTML` of `<div id="results"></div>` with the sorted numbers. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok thanks i will be trying this this morning